# How get org.olap4j.metadata.Cube from Mondrian OlapConnection

Tags: olap-cube, mondrian

I develop the web application with Mondrian OLAP engine with Olap4j and should present/display data to user.
From Java code i create OlapConnection  and try get all cubes from database.

```
OlapConnection c = (OlapConnection) DriverManager.getConnection(connStr);
OlapDatabaseMetaData  md = c.getMetaData();
ResultSet cubes = (Cube)md.getCubes("wdi", "", "wdi");
```

But i have only ResultSet type,  how i can get all cubes by type org.olap4j.metadata.Cube?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

org.olap4j.metadata.Cube cube =   c.getOlapSchema().getCubes().get("wdi");